# Software stack to build modern website?

Tags: python, java, .net, node.js, react

As a newbie I am trying to decide which of the following stacks to devote effort to build a website which will be easier as well as good for future high-volume website:

- Frontend=(React or Angular) + Backend=(Expressjs+Nodejs) or
- Frontend=(React or Angular) + Backend=(Python+Django) or
- Frontend=(React or Angular) + Backend=(C# .Net core) or
- Frontend=(React or Angular) + Backend=(Java+Springboot) would be too hard for newbie I believe.
- anything else better, golang etc. are too new wait and watch more time

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are good reasons to choose any one of those and no particular "right" answer.  All those environments are used in very high volume web-sites and all have rich sets of tools and libraries.  What programming experience do you already have?  In what languages?  What type of server application will this be?  Do you have any affinity for any particular language (Javascript, C#, Java, Python)?  Do you have any particular desire or aversion to being tied to Microsoft for tools and supported platforms?

Comment: Thanks for the reply it helps, just have bit of coding in perl, python, c not much. Backend will be mysql such as storing some e-commerce data and dispay/update on webpages.

Comment: Angular + PHP works for me. 95% of the web runs on PHP.

Comment: React(frontend)+PHP/Laravel(backend api/db) would also be worth doing.